# Kafka Streams - How to know when state restoration is complete

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Except from checking the application log, is it possible to programatically check when the state restoration is complete? For instance, I would like to set the readiness probe to "Alive" for a Kafka Streams application in OpenShift when the state restoration is complete.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [KafkaStreams.setGlobalStateRestoreListner](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.4.0/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.html#setGlobalStateRestoreListener-org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.StateRestoreListener-) to set a `StateRestoreListener` that provides for notification of when [the restoration completes](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.4.0/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/StateRestoreListener.html#onRestoreEnd-org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition-java.lang.String-long-) with the `onRestoreEnd` method.

Let me know how it works out for you.

HTH,
Bill

Comment: I ended up using the `initialDelaySecond` parameter for the OpenShift liveness- and readiness probes. The value for `initialDelaySecond` was set to  ~3 minutes to allow the pod to restore its state.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by registing a state listener that listen to every state change happened to the streaming threads (created, rebalancing, pending_shutdown, running...).

Here is a sample code of how to register stateListener

```
            streams.setStateListener((KafkaStreams.State newState, KafkaStreams.State old)->{
                logger.info()
                        .message("Thread state has changed from {" + old.name() + "} to {" + newState.name() + "}")
                        .log();
                // here you can either register a metric or a global state variable that can be used in a health probe api.
            });
```

Comment: The problem is that the `RUNNING` state lacks some granularity. `RUNNING` both means that the stream is processing new records, but it also means that the stream is perfoming state restoration. There should be a `RESTORING` state, but unfortunately it does not exist...